# JSF 2 Send info to ManagedBeans file on respective checkbox click

Tags: jsf

I have a table of checkboxes like [Table of Row & Column Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX3qi.jpg)

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{userBean.gridRows}" var="tempRow">
   <td>
      <h:selectManyCheckbox class="cb_list">
         <f:selectItem itemValue="#{tempRow}|rows" itemLabel="" />
      </h:selectManyCheckbox>
   </td>
</ui:repeat>
```

On the click of each checkbox i need to send the related info to ManagedBeans file, like if checkbox for Row A has been checked, i need to send the info that Row A has been selected.
This needs to be done without using JS and without the use of Button.

How to do that?

Comment: I guess that's not possible without using JavaScript.

Comment: @stg: please create this as an answer since it is the only correct one